# "Command not found" when attempting integer equality in bash

Tags: bash

Ok, this is probably going to be ultra obvious to anyone that has spent more time with bash than I have.

I'm trying to run this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ["1" -eq "2"] 
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

but when I execute the file, it sends back

```
./test.sh: line 3: 1: command not found
False
```

There must be something major I'm missing.  I've seen people use a semicolon after the brackets, this doesn't seem to make any difference... :S

Comment: [ is a program, try `which [` and you'll see. And you can't execute a program with arguments written without a whitespace... (And as others have answered, -eq is for integers only. Which it will tell you when using [ correct)

Comment: Everyone already said that you need a space after `[`.  The *reason* is that `[` is a command -- it's an alias for `test`.  These days it's a shell builtin but you can find `/bin/[` on most systems.

Comment: @plundra: Those *are* integers. See my comment on RageZ's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash, command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694586/bash-command-not-found)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yep eq is used only for arithmetic comparaisons.

for string comparison you have to use `=`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "1" = "2" ] 
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

plus you need some space around the brackets.

Comment: Numbers are strings in the shell. The quotes don't change the fact that they're numbers. `[ 10 -gt 2 ]` is true. *Comparisons*, on the other hand, can be for strings or numbers. One example, you've shown. Others that are specific to shells that support `[[`: string: `[[ "10" > "2" ]]` (false) or `[[ "10" -gt "2" ]]` (true). Again, it's not the quotes that make the difference.

Comment: Spaces!  I knew it was going to be something small.  And people complain about *python's* use of significant whitespace. :S

Comment: @Margaret Heh. The thing shell does that's weird here is having `[` *not be syntax*, but instead be a regular command (as far as the parser is concerned; there's actually a built-in implementation so `/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/[` aren't used by common shells, but that's just a performance optimization). It's completely normal to need a space between the name of a command and its arguments.

Answer (score 40):

You need to add a space after the `[` and before the `]` like so:

```
if [ "1" -eq "2" ]
```

However, that way is deprecated and the better method to use is:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ((1 == 2)) 
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Comment: Can you detail on that change, in what context is that a valid statement ? Which shells ?

Comment: @tvCa which statement are you referring to, the requirement for a space after `[` or `(( ))` ?

Comment: Yes ... I mean about using (( )) instead of [ ] - From what I read, the replacement for [ ] is [[ ]] - and not (( ))

Comment: @tvCa In bash `(( ))` is used for arithmetic evaluation which is exactly what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding spaces around your brackets:

```
if [ "1" -eq "2" ]
```