# bash, command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm having trouble fixing the error in this bash script, I seriously have no idea what I did wrong, any help is appreciated thanks

```
[centoslive@livecd ~]$ sh ListFich.sh test
Synthese, Question 2
ListFich.sh: line 9: [-d: command not found
Il n'y a aucun repertoire qui se nomme test
ListFich.sh: line 15: [-f: command not found
Il n'y a aucun fichier qui se nomme test
[centoslive@livecd ~]$
```

```
#!bin/bash

echo "Synthese, Question 2"

if test $# -eq 0; then
    echo "Argument Manquants"
    exit 1 
else 
    if [-d $1];then
        ls -d $1
        exit 1
    else 
        echo "Il n'y a aucun repertoire qui se nomme $1"
    fi
    if [-f $1]; then
        if [ -s $1]; then
            ls -l $1
            exit 1
        else 
            ls -l $1
            echo "Le fichier $1 est vide"
            exit 1
        fi
    else 
        echo "Il n'y a aucun fichier qui se nomme $1"   
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You seem to be exiting 1 on success; by convention that indicates failure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a space **after** `[` and **before** `]`.

```
[ -d $1 ]
 ^     ^
```

Comment: @JoeE: While you are at it, consider using `[[` and `]]` -- bash's more powerful builtins, which provide additional operators (=~, <, >) and remove the need to quote your string operands.

Comment: this [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) present the main differences between **[** and **[[**.

Comment: Care to explain why and give some reference link? That would make this answer so much more useful!

Comment: @Kissaki see the previous comment.

Comment: @tarrsailah I saw that comment. This is mainly / targeted to be a Q&A site though rather than a Q&A&C site. Answers should be as complete as possible so not everybody looking for an answer needs to read all the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces before and after `[` and `]`. See `help [` for details.