# Need to check input arguments Bash Shell Script on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I want to check input arguments presence on a bash script on OSX.  I do:

```
if [-z "$1"]
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/deploy.sh: line 8: [-z: command not found
```

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482377/bash-shell-script-check-input-argument)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Command not found" when attempting integer equality in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468824/command-not-found-when-attempting-integer-equality-in-bash)

Answer (score 7):

You need a space around the condition:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]

    ^       ^
```