# An error line not affecting the shell script in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

./menu: line 12: [1: command not found

This thing keeps showing up even though doesn't affect script's functionality.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/rvs130@studin.aubgin.$

function press_enter
{
    echo ""
    echo -n "Press Enter to continue"
    read
    clear
}

choice=
until ["$choice" = "0"]; do
        echo ''
        echo '          SMILEY SERVER MENU'
        echo '1 - To view the available smilies'
        echo '2 - Search for a smiley'
        echo '3 - Add a new smiley'
        echo '4 - Delete a smiley'
        echo '5 - Edit smiley or description'
        echo ''
        echo '0 - Exit'
        echo 'Enter your choice: '
        read choice

        case "$choice" in
                1)
                cat smilies.txt;;
                2)
                echo 'Please enter the name of the smiley you want to see: '
                read name
                echo 'Match found: '
                grep $name smilies.txt ;;
                3)
                echo 'Enter the smiley you want to add followed'
                echo 'by a space and description: '
                read newsmiley
                echo "$newsmiley" >> smilies.txt
                echo 'New smiley added.' ;;
                4)
                echo 'Enter a smiley or its description you want to delete: '
                read delsmiley
                sed -i /"$delsmiley"/d smilies.txt ;;
                5)
                echo 'Enter a word you want to edit, space'
                echo 'and then desired replacement word: '
                read word1 word2
                replace "$word1" "$word2" -- smilies.txt ;;
                0) exit ;;
                *)
                echo 'Please enter a valid choice.'; press_enter
        esac
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Command not found" when attempting integer equality in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468824/command-not-found-when-attempting-integer-equality-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

You **must** have spaces around `[` and `]`. What happens in your script is that the first time round, `$choice` is empty, so the line evaluates to `[ = "0"]`, which *should* result in an error like `` bash: [: missing `]' `` the first time round (which, unless you `set -o errexit`, will not affect execution). After choosing 1 and coming round to the test line again, it evaluates to `[1 = "0"]`, where `[1` is interpreted as the command you want to run. What you want is:

```
until [ "$choice" -eq 0 ]
```

Also, that's not a valid [shebang line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#BashGuide.2FCommandsAndArguments.Scripts).

Comment: I would change this : until [ "$choice" = "0" ] ; do"